# .NET 4.5 .exe producing error: Unsupported 16-bit application

Tags: c#, windows-7, exe, 16-bit

We have produced several other .exe programs that work fine.
Have no idea why this one cannot run on a 64-bit OS.
Have specifically selected 64-bit in the project settings and when building it in TeamCity.

Project settings:
Conditional compilation symbols: Empty
Define DEBUG constant: False
Define TRACE constant: True
Platform target: x64
Prefer 32-bit: disabled
Allow unsafe code: false
Optimize code: true (false same error just uses the .exe file name as title instead of the 16-bit stuff)

Edit:
When debugging the app (the error only occurs on a server) it produced the error: BadImageFormatException.

We are using NDesk.Options for reading arguments.
Will try removing that.

Comment: Is it possible it tries to call something that's 16 bit? A library or something?

Comment: It is a bizarre error message of course.  You'll have to consider file corruption, anti-malware would be a long shot, that sort of issue.  Use another machine.

Comment: Turns out it was caused by our deployment process, it was replacing variables, but not just in the config, in everything...